# Debug Blazor circuit errors

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have stuck for a couple days now.. There is an error in my Blazor server application, no errors get thrown in Visual Studio, it appears in the console debug tools..

> Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (TypeError: i.parentNode is null)
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: i.parentNode is null
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

This gives me no clue.. I dont know what else to try to get to where the error is happening

I have tried Stepping through the code, but it happens even on pages where there is no code (I suspect startup.cs but no errors thrown)

I have also made bare MainLayout, still error

AppSettings

```json
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  ...
```

startup.cs / configure services

```cs
services
    .AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });
```

but still I only get those three lines

Comment: Where is your `i.parentNode`?

Comment: i.parentNode is something in blazor.server.js.. but anywho.. I had blazor.server.js in there twice.. now seems to have resolved